# What are these components I pulled from a power supply?

Tags: identification, components

I pulled these from a computer power supply. At first I thought they were resistors, but they are around 5-10 Ω. I'm guessing they are inductors, but I can't find a chart which matches this color pattern.

If you know what they are, can you enlighten me?

[image]

I decided to break one open. Ceramic core (I couldn't cut it with wire snippers) but I chipped off the outer layer... Super low value resistor?

[image]

I believe @hacktastical has the description right. I did a search using some of his terms and found this:

https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-materials/wirewound-resistor/#

Comment: Two pairs look identical. Can you confirm? In fact three look identical and there may be another three that are identical too. Please rationalize your picture. Even if they were unambiguously identified, the risk of reusing them is something I would not take but, maybe you have another reason?

Comment: So why exactly are you pulling out components that you don't even know what they do? Are you trying to repair something?

Comment: Anyway most do definitely look like resistors and if there's gold/silver "lining" (pun intended) on them then they will have low values. See for example https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/6/4/Resistors.png. Some might be thermistors I suppose, which aren't unlikely to be found in a power supply. (And yes, color coding of TH components is possible one of the dumbest inventions ever made by mankind.)

Comment: Years ago while reverse engineering an old phone/answering machine for fun (playing with equipment in the lab) I noticed similar things. The designers had used wire-wound resistors for their small inductances...

Comment: in fact they are resistors AND inductors ;-)

Comment: @Andyaka "Rationalize" my picture? I don't know what you mean. The color codes seem identical, which is why I'm asking what they are

Comment: @Lundin Um, because it's a defunct computer power supply, it's mine, and I'm salvaging components out of it for my parts bins.

Comment: I mean, it's aged, oxidated, possibly broken components that you don't know what they do. Whereas a brand new through-hole resistor is basically free, you just pay for the freight...

Comment: That's why I'm asking what they are. Some things are learning experiences.

Comment: break one open .

Comment: The one you busted open looks like a non-inductively wound resistor (there's two coils that wrap the core in opposite directions, so their fields cancel each other.)

Comment: So if I measured 5-10 ohms, that would seem to make sense, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called wire resistors and they have low ohmic value. For example, in the photo, the yellow resistor has a value of 2.2 ohms (third band is golden). If third band were silver, it would have a value of 0.22 ohms.